# Chemical formulae with dopants / Formulae containing ”:“

Tags: chemistry, mhchem

I'm trying to write some substances with dopants in them, e. g. ”InO<sub>2</sub>:Sn.“
Although I could split up the formula every time it contained a dopant, this wasn't really smart to do and I'd also get in trouble with line endings/non-breaking spaces at some point.

How to bring a colon (`:`) into `\ce{}`?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
    \ce{InO2}:\ce{Sn}
    %\ce{InO2:Sn}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\ce{InO2{:}Sn}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, `\ce` only accepts a fixed set of characters and the colon isn't among them.

You might make a feature request. In the meantime, you can work around the problem with a trick.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\newcommand{\dop}{{:}}

\begin{document}

\ce{InO2}:\ce{Sn}

\ce{InO2\dop Sn}

\end{document}
```

[image]